# $ X_n $ independent random variables  zero one question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For $A := \left\{ \sum X_n \text { converges} \right\}$, I'm wondering how to get started showing
$P (A)\in\{0,1\}$.

Is Borel Cantelli a good strategy ?

Comment: Kolmogorov's $0$-$1$ law?

Comment: Maybe Kolmogorov zero-one law?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, hadn't covered it yet, so it's quite helpful!

Comment: What are the tools you're allowed to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others, the random variables $(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ are independent hence, by [Kolmogorov zero-one law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero-one_law), the sigma-algebras $F_k$ generated by $(X_{n+k})_{n\geqslant0}$ have a trivial intersection $F_{\infty}$, in the sense that every $C$ in $F_\infty$ is such that $\mathrm P(C)=0$ or $\mathrm P(C)=1$.

Hence, the task is to prove that the event $A=\big[\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0} X_n\ \text{converges}\big]$ is in $F_\infty$, or, equivalently, that $A$ is in  $F_k$ for every $k\geqslant0$.

To this end, fix $k\geqslant0$ and note that $A=A_k$ with $A_k=\big[\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0} X_{n+k}\ \text{converges}\big]$. By definition, $A_k$ depends on $(X_{n+k})_{n\geqslant0}$ only, hence $A=A_k$ is in $F_k$. QED.

Comment: This solution bypasses any precise translation of the convergence of a series in terms of the behaviour of its partial sums, which unnecessarily complicates things when the question is only about the measurability of the event that the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

In other to expand Dilip Sarwate's and Ilya's comments, let $\mathcal F_n:=\sigma(X_k,k\geq n)$ the smallest $\sigma$-algebra making the random variables $X_k$, for $k\geq n$, measurable. We have to show that $A\in \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\mathcal F_n$ in order to apply [Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero-one_law). We can write 
$$A=\bigcap_{p\geq 1}\bigcup_{N\geq p}\bigcap_{N\leq n<m}\left\{\omega:\left|\sum_{j=n+1}^mX_j(\omega)\right|\le \frac 1p\right\}.$$
Since the sequence $\left\{\bigcup_{N\geq p}\bigcap_{N\leq n<m}\left\{\omega:\left|\sum_{j=n+1}^mX_j(\omega)\right|\le \frac 1p\right\}\right\}_p$ is decreasing, we can in fact write for all $p_0$ that $A=
\bigcap_{p\geq p_0}\bigcup_{N\geq p}\bigcap_{N\leq n<m}\left\{\omega:\left|\sum_{j=n+1}^mX_j(\omega)\right|\le \frac 1p\right\}$. Since $\bigcup_{N\geq p}\bigcap_{N\leq n<m}\left\{\omega:\left|\sum_{j=n+1}^mX_j(\omega)\right|\le \frac 1p\right\}\in\mathcal F_p\subset \mathcal F_{p_0}$, we get that $A\in\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\mathcal F_n$, so $A$ is a tail event and $P(A)\in \{0,1\}$.

Note that there are cases on which $P(A)=0$, for example $X_n(\omega)=1$ for all
$\omega$. We can also have $P(A)=1$ if $X_n(\omega)=0$ for all $n$ and all $\omega$.

Series of independent random variables have nice properties, for example convergence in probability is the same thing as convergence almost everywhere. We also have [three series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem), by Kolmogorov.